# Legend name and color need to be displayed in the export of highchart as image

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am trying to export bloxplot high chart as an image in my angular 4 application.I am able to see the burger menu when my chart is loaded after adding the reference in the app.module. I am also able to export the image by clicking on the burger menu and selecting png or jpeg options. The trouble i am having is setting the legend colors and labels while exporting the highchart. As you can see in the image below, it is displaying series 1 and series 2.Do I need to write logic in the exporting section of the chart ?

[image]

I need to instead display the legend name and color as follows

[image]

The series that I am using to bind to the highchart is as follows

```
 series: [{
            data: [
            color:"#5D63D3"
            high:1381733.354653
            low:1375002.43018757
            median:1378397.06388383
            name:"Captive Options"
            q1:1377657.3051449
            q3:1379137.30789384]
       }]
```

Boxplot chart component

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { ShortNumberFormatPipe } from '@wtw/toolkit';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-box-plot-chart',
    template: '<chart [options]="options" (load)="getInstance($event.context)"></chart>',
    styles: [`
        chart{
              display: block;
              width: 100% !important;
              padding:0;
        }
    `]
})

//, width: number
export class BoxPlotChartComponent implements OnInit {
    static chart(shortNumberFormatPipe: ShortNumberFormatPipe, translate: TranslateService, moduleName: string, height: number, graphLegendTitle: string) {
        return {
            chart: {
                type: 'boxplot',
                reflow: true,
                height: height
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                chartOptions: {
                    legend: {
                        allowHTML: true,
                        enabled: true,
                        margin: 25,
                        itemMarginTop: 0,
                        symbolRadius: 0,
                        symbolHeight: 20,
                        symbolWidth: 20,
                        useHTML: true,
                        align: 'right',
                        verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                    }
                }
            },

            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            xAxis: {

                lineWidth: 0,
                minorGridLineWidth: 0,
                lineColor: 'transparent',
                labels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                minorTickLength: 0,
                tickLength: 0
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: ''
                }, plotLines: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                shared: true,
                useHTML: true,

                formatter: function () {
                    let isMillionNumber: boolean = false;
                    const row = function (label, value) {
                        const key = 'CAPTIVES.RESULTS.COMMON.';

                        return '<tr><td style="font-size:10px;">' + translate.instant(key + label) + ': </td>'
                            + '<td style="font-size:10px;"><b>' + value + '</b></td></tr>';
                    };

                    const transformNumber = function (value) {
                        isMillionNumber = validateMillionNumber(value);
                        if (isMillionNumber || moduleName === 'eva')
                            return shortNumberFormatPipe.transform(value, 2);
                        else
                            return shortNumberFormatPipe.transform(value, 0);
                    };

                    const table = function (format, point) {
                        let txt = '<strong style="font-size:12px;color:' + point.color + '">' + point.name + '</strong><br><br>';
                        txt += '<table>';
                        if (moduleName === 'npv') {
                            txt += row('HIGH', format(point.high));
                            txt += row('Q3', format(point.q3));
                            txt += row('MEDIAN', format(point.median));
                            txt += row('Q1', format(point.q1));
                            txt += row('LOW', format(point.low));
                        } else if (moduleName === 'eva') {
                            txt += row('HIGH', format(point.high) + '%');
                            txt += row('Q3', format(point.q3) + '%');
                            txt += row('MEDIAN', format(point.median) + '%');
                            txt += row('Q1', format(point.q1) + '%');
                            txt += row('LOW', format(point.low) + '%');
                        }
                        txt += '</table>';
                        return txt;
                    };

                    let point = this.points[0].point;

                    return table(transformNumber, point);

                    function validateMillionNumber(millionNumber: number) {
                        return millionNumber >= 1000000;
                    }

                },
            },
            series: []
        };
    }

    public options: any;
    chart: any;
    @Input() public series: any;
    @Input() public moduleName: string = '';
    @Input() public height: number = 400;

    private shortNumberFormatPipe = new ShortNumberFormatPipe();

    constructor(private _translate: TranslateService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        //let graphLegendTitle: string = this._translate.instant('CAPTIVES.RESULTS.COMMON.GRAPH_LEGEND_TITLE');
        let graphLegendTitle: string = '';
        this.options = BoxPlotChartComponent.chart(this.shortNumberFormatPipe, this._translate, this.moduleName, this.height, graphLegendTitle);
    }

    getInstance(chartInstance): void {
        this.chart = chartInstance;
        this.redraw();
    }


    ngOnChanges(data: any) {
        if (!data.series.currentValue || !this.chart) return;
        data.series.currentValue.map(s => {
            this.chart.addSeries(s);
        });
        this.chart.reflow();
    }

    redraw() {
        if (!this.chart) return;
        this.chart.addSeries(this.series);
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to touch the exporting logic... Can you recreate this in a jsfiddle? I went to the highcharts website and tried to recreate this in a boxplot with your `legend` and `exporting` objects but didn't have any luck, it still exported correctly.

Comment: Please see the example in the jsfiddle that i have created  https://jsfiddle.net/phyrsvc0/10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in your series object. You should have your object look like this

```
series: [{
   color:"#5D63D3"
   data: [
       high:1381733.354653
       low:1375002.43018757
       median:1378397.06388383
       name:"Captive Options"
       q1:1377657.3051449
       q3:1379137.30789384]
}]
```

working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rhavelka/phyrsvc0/18/ (let me know if it is working. I don't see it in the list of my fiddles but I can follow the link successfully)